# Palindrome chain length in Python coming up incorrect

Tags: python, count, palindrome

I feel like this should work correctly but I get an error with the count being 1 less than it should be.

```
def palindrome_chain_length(n):
    count = 0
    while str(n) != str(n)[::-1] :
        n = n+n
        count += 1
    else:
        return count
```

Comment: shouldn't it be: `n += int(str(n)[::-1])` instead of `n = n + n` ?

Comment: Thanks @alfasin !
You're correct, it should be n += int(str(n)[::-1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just get count 1 less than you want, start with `count = 1`.
And it seems to me that it should be:

```
n += int(str(n)[::-1])
```

instead of:

```
n = n + n
```

(see comment @alfasin).

Comment: Thanks, count = 1 starting out would be incorrect for a number that is already a palindrome, but you are correct about it being n += int(str(n)[::-1])
Thanks again!

Comment: You can't use n[::-1] because int object is not subscriptable. So you have to transform it to string, reverse and transform again.